# Вырезание учатска url

Tags: регулярные-выражения

есть url http://www.kmssport.ru/catalog/group/item/detskiy_sportivnyi_kompleks_dsk_alpinistik_dsk_1
необходимо избавиться от catalog/group/
нужно регулярное выражения для вырезания этой части.

Comment: str_replace() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Чем обычный replace не угодил - он почти есть в любом языке или СУБД?

Answer (score 0):

На примере Oracle:

```
REGEXP_replace(
    'http://www.kmssport.ru/catalog/group/item/detskiy_sportivnyi_kompleks_dsk_alpinistik_dsk_1', 
    '(catalog/group/)',
    ''
)
```